# How to create a TODO pattern containing 3 consecutive question mark characters?

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

Similar to being able to type "// todo " or "// fix" and having the IDE recognize them as TODO patterns (thus, changing the text color of the pattern and subsequent text), I'd also like to be able to type "// ???" or "//???" and have those patterns recognized.

In File > Settings > Editor > TODO, I've tried the following patterns for a new pattern entry, none of which has worked:

```
\b???\b.*  
\b\?\?\?\b.*  
\b\\?\\?\\?\b.*  
\b\?{3}\b.*  
\b\\?{3}\b.*
```

Can anyone suggest the correct pattern to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\B\?{3}\B.*
```

The tricky aspect of the requirement is the use of the ? character, which is a non-word character. The Word Boundary (\b) only applies to a word character (and a white space character), thus was not matching the first and last ? characters in my pattern.  By using the Not-A-Word-Boundary (\B), non-word characters were matched.